# Apps Script Execution API "network error occurred" in Firefox

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-drive-api

There are the following problems or bugs(?) in Google Apps Script Execution API.

Error in Firefox "A network error occurred and the request could not be completed." (after about 1 minute execution).

Chrome, IE, Safari return the result value "ok" (regardless of the time).

How to fix it? Thanks.

```
//apps script part
function getAction(){
  var result={};
  Utilities.sleep(1000*120); //wait 2~ minutes
  result['value']='ok';
  return result; 
}

//client javascript part
var payload ={'test':'a'}
var request = {
    'function': 'getAction',
    'parameters': [payload],
    'devMode': true
};
var scriptId='your script ID';
var op = gapi.client.request({
    'root': 'https://script.googleapis.com',
    'path': 'v1/scripts/' + scriptId + ':run',
    'method': 'POST',
    'body': request
});
op.execute(function(resp){
    //Error in Firefox "A network error occurred and the request could not be completed." (after about 1 minute)
    //Chrome, IE, Safari return the result value "ok" (regardless of the time)
});
```

Comment: Is that all the code? could you explain what are you trying to do? what is the function that fails? how to reproduce?